# R - How can I insert/shift a value in a specific row?

Tags: r

I want to insert a value (actually a "NA") in a specific row at a specific column in a matrix. I would like the rest of the row (the subsequent columns) to shift by one as a consequence of the insertion. No values should be deleted in the process, I want to insert a value, not replace one.

**Example**

My input matrix looks like:

```
1 2 3 4 NA
1 2 3 4 NA
1 2 3 4 NA
```

Something like:

> insertShift (insert = NA, where = df[2, 3])

Output matrix should look like:

```
1 2 3 4 NA
1 2 NA 3 4
1 2 3 4 NA
```

Comment: A matrix has to be rectangular, and your desired output isn't.  What do you want to happen to rows 1 and 3?  Or do you want a list of vectors (i.e of the current rows)?

Comment: Convert matrix to a list by row, then length can be different. It would be nice to know why? What is the next step?

Comment: On 2nd row last value, if it was 5, would it just be dropped?

Comment: Good point @AndrewGustar. I've edited my example so it matches my situation better. My matrix is filled in with `NA` when I'm importing it, and I'd need the shifted rows to replace `NA` values that are present in the last columns.

Comment: @zx8754 it would not be 5, it would be `NA`. Basically, all my last columns are filled in with `NA` values (I know the final number of columns my matrix should have).

Comment: Seems like a matix might not be the best choice of data structures. What exactly are you trying to accomplish. Seems like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `mat[2,3:ncol(mat)] <- c(NA,mat[2,3:(ncol(mat)-1)])`

Comment: @zx8754 There is no real next step... To explain, I have data from a simulation software where there are shifts in columns (the software fills in the matrix column per column while it should insert a few NA every now and then). I am able to get for each column the row numbers where a NA should have been inserted, and I want to correct that. So next step is essentially to have nice clean data I can actually work on.

Comment: @AndrewGustar you nailed it! Looks like exactly what I'm trying to do, thank you. I can mark it as answer if you post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work... `mat[2,3:ncol(mat)] <- c(NA,mat[2,3:(ncol(mat)-1)])`